# burninate [maxlength]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

There is a tag [maxlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxlength) which has:

- 241 questions
- no followers
- most of top-answerers answered only one question (the same with top-askers)

When I was scanning through these questions I had an impression that almost every one is far away from the others. There are questions regarding HTML, Matlab, PHP and many others languages and frameworks.
The only one common element of these questions is some kind of boundary. It is either limitation encountered in some environment or limitation which we set to other users.

I think that this tag should be burninated beause:

1. You cannot be an expert in [maxlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxlength)
2. If question is tagged only [maxlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxlength) then we realy have no idea what is it about.

**Should this tag be burninated?**

Comment: One of these days, someone's going to have to explain to me how "being an expert" in something has any relevance to tag creation.  It is curious that 241 questions managed to find a use for what appears to be a rather obscure tag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging 'Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions'

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: That statement in  stackoverflow.com/help/tagging is just that: a statement.  It is not guidance for tag creation.  The blog post doesn't talk about experts at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If oficial help page is not guidance for tag creation then what is?

Comment: You're reading too much into that help page.  It doesn't say anywhere on that page "Tags must encompass an expert subject area to be valid."

Comment: Contextual tags are not meta tags.

Comment: @RobertHarvey more direct questions: it's useful for bringing attention to experts that are able to answer those questions? It would be answered without that tag? Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? I think it fails, all of them.

Comment: Give people the power to create new tags all the time, because in the future those tags could be used to make a A.I coder which brain will be learn from stackoverflow questions / tags etc.!

Comment: @Braiam:  In general, the primary purpose of tags is *categorization.*  All of your direct questions are nice to haves, but none of them are essential (except for the third one).  I think it's fair to say that tags that have these things make better tags, but they're certainly not required for tag creation, nor does their absence necessarily make a tag bad.

Comment: Let me put it this way, @Robert. The main and fundamental propose of the tags is to connect questions with the people that are able to answer them. Any tag that doesn't create this connection is at best superfluous or irrelevant and at worst poisonous, counterproductive or hazardous, and it's very likely that needs to be exchanged for tags that does fulfill those tasks. I think that we are in the tangent here. Anyways, "maxlenght" without context isn't useful in any question, it can prevent others more relevant tags from being applied and gives the impression that any "keyword" can be a tag.

Comment: @Braiam: and that is where I think we differ.  Sure, people use tags to find questions to answer, especially the large tags like C#, but that's not their only purpose, and never has been.