# Why was my edit rejected by community user?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, community-user

Today my suggested edit was rejected and I don't know why? But I will start with brief introdution.

I am on StackOverflow for 50 days. At the beginning I made several errors. I was doing lots of bad edits. It is described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276402/100-edits-in-one-evening-is-it-wrong). But I've lerned my lesson and now I don't do many edits. I choose question to edit rather carefully and I try to correct everything what is wrong with the post. I participate also on meta site. I initiated several burnination requests (example [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277705/burninate-ratio) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280159/burninate-maxlength)) which are waiting either for volunteers or for me to have over 2k reputation points to complete.

Today I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768793/selected-option-in-view-when-size-is-greater-than-1) post. There were following issues to correct in it:

1. Tag [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) should be removed because it excerpt says: `DO NOT USE THIS TAG. It is ambiguous and not helpful.`
2. Tag [size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/size) should be removed because it excerpt says: `Please don't use this tag in your posts - it's too generic to usefully categorise your question.`
3. Tag [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) should be replaced with [html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) because in its wiki there is: `Do not use this tag for this purpose, use html-select instead.`
4. Multiline code example was surrounded with two backticks which is intended only for inline. So these backticks should be removed.
5. There was no indentation in code.

I corrected them all and added such description:

> Question was tagged very wrongly: [option] and [size] tags are not recommended. [select] is not for HTML questions

But later I found my suggested edit rejected:

[image: review]

From this description I deduced that I omitted something, that there was something more to improve and reviewer rejected my edit and then edited it correcting what I spotted and what I omitted. To my astonishment user corrected only number 4 from my above list. And now I am puzzled and I don't know what exactly I did wrong. Can you explain me this?

I am not writing this post to complain but to learn something and be a better editer in the future.

---

**EDIT:**

This post is not duplicate of [Why did the Community user reject my suggested edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250129/why-did-the-community-user-reject-my-suggested-edit) as some of you suggest. In that post OP's edit conflicted with edit of original poster made in 5 minut grace period. My edit was made to old question. Grace period not last for years. Before I posted my question I serched for similar posts.
**Conflict** rejection is much different from **veto** rejection.

Comment: Community only rejects edits to deal with conflicts. Another user saw your edit and felt it was not good enough. so the user rejected it and made his own edit

Comment: @psubsee2003: not so much a conflict as an explicit veto rejection here.

Comment: @Pokechu22 It is not duplicate. It is not conflicted edit.

Comment: @Pokechu22: wrong duplicate; there are different reasons CU can be involved. In addition, the specific rejection by the reviewer here bears addressing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops.  I don't think I can cancel my flag though.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The reviewer (Rudi, listed just above Community User) used the *Reject and Edit* button; but to reject your edit Community User has to step in to cast a *moderator* vote (a veto vote) as a single reviewer cannot on their own reject a suggested edit otherwise. This is an *automatic* consequence of the reviewer picking that specific option. Rudi then edited the post to make a different change instead.

Apparently Rudi did not agree to the tag change; [their revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2768793/revisions) only removed the backticks, left the indentation alone, and left the tags in place.

Only Rudi can explain exactly why they choose to ignore the tag changes here; I agree that your edit was better, and have re-applied your change there (but I also added [html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) here). I also left a comment for the reviewer to give them a chance to give their view.

Looking over your recent suggested edits, I'd say your track record is otherwise *excellent*. I'd not worry about this specific rejection.

Comment: Just to offer some clarity, I had missed the tag changes at first sight and If I remember correctly had rejected the edit on the basis of a grammatical error added to the first line. In hind-sight. I think the `Improve edit` button would have been more appropriate.

Otherwise I agree with Martijn's assessment.

Comment: @Rudi: ah, yes, there is an [edit on the first line](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6487050) that is grammatically incorrect. I'd have used *Improve*, not *Reject and Edit* here, to clear that up.

Comment: @Rudi Thanks for explanation. It is partially my fault then. I did slight change in the first line to satisfy 6-characters requirement. I pay attention to avoiding grammar errors but my English is not perfect and such situations may happen. Everything is clear now. Curiosity is satisfied.

Comment: @rtruszk - It's more my fault than yours. The review system is there to stop people making mistakes. Unfortunately reviewers are people too, and so we make mistakes as well. Glad it's been cleared up.

Comment: @Rudi Wait, you mean you're *not* a robo-reviewer?!