# Change misleading suggested edit reject message by community user

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits, community-user

In [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6504959), the community user rejected a suggested edit with the message:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

I've noticed this seems to occur everytime another reviewer Rejects and Edits. I believe this is a bad message because:

1. It's phrasing might make a user believe the community user is rejecting the edit because it's "too minor"; it didn't address more major issues. However, [minor edits are good](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/1607043) and this may make the user believe only major edits are allowed. I believe [the following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/211026), from a post explaining removal of the too minor reason, is justification for the current message:

   > If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, then it isn't too minor!

   However, in practice, what usually happens is it gets approved (improving overall quality, even if it's not as much as it could be) or it gets rejected as "no improvement whatsoever," if it made no difference to quality.
2. This is automated, and there's no guarantee the subsequent edit is actually better. I admit the [review I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6504959) is an extreme case, as the question asker Rejected and Edited by adding a code dump. This is bad because the community user's message encourages the edit suggester to see what they should have done. The suggester then sees a "good example," which might not actually be one, but on top of that, there is no actual way they could have anticipated that they "should have" edited in a bunch of code.

For example, *both* of these reasons negatively affected [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6487050), where both editor and reviewer are shown to be acting in good faith according to [this recent meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280357/1607043).

I suggest replacing the message with the following, which I see being used in other cases:

> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

Comment: I had a similar experience with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26472750/500098. The suggested new message would have been much clearer to me!

Comment: Voting to close my own question in favor of a newer duplicate question as that one managed to get more votes and an answer.